# What does "their own qualifications" refer in this context?

Tags: meaning

> The manager is responsible for the following:
>
> 1. The designation of persons working under his or her supervision.
> 2. **Their own qualifications** for working with the type of firearms being used.

In this context, does "their qualification" mean the qualification of the persons designated by the manager? Or does it mean the qualification of the manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we call an **ambiguous antecedent**. It has a relative pronoun, *their*, but the text before it gives two possible referents. It could mean the manager, or the "persons working under his or her supervision".

Often, you have a syntactically ambiguous antecedent, but it's not a problem because the semantics make it obvious what is referred to. In this case, however, it is well and truly ambiguous.

One clue we have as to what they mean, however, is the use of ***his or her*** in the previous bullet point. That indicates that the author doesn't use the singular *they*, meaning that *their* in the next point is most likely plural, and therefore must refer to the "persons working under ... supervision".

On the other hand, we also have ***their own***, which suggests some sense of it being reflexive, that someone is responsible for something of their own. That would suggest it is the qualifications of the manager.

So, it could semantically be either, it could syntactically be either, and the minor pointers we get in the text are pointing in different directions.

If it's a legal document, or a policy, or whatever, we can finally fall back on the idea that items in a list should stand independently. You should be able to read each of them along with the text before the list and get meaning from it without needing to read the others, unless explicit reference is made. That would suggest it's the manager's qualifications. However, exactly what counts as an explicit reference varies between authorities, so *their* could be considered such a reference.

Basically, whoever drafted that needs a stern talking to. If I *had to* decide what I thought it meant, the reflexive *own* sways me and I think it means the manager's qualifications. But it should be written less ambiguously.

Comment: I don't think there's any ambiguity at all. The presence of the "reflexive" possessive element ***own*** makes it clear ***their*** is simply being used as a gender-neutral alternative to preceding ***his or her*** (i.e. - a singular reference to the manager, not a plural reference to the persons working under "them" :)

Comment: I agree that's where it points, overall, but whoever drafted it needs a talking to because they've been inconsistent and unclear. Especially if this is some sort of policy document - ambiguity in policies is very bad.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that's a pretty sound argument for what the writer **intended**; but in a formal written context, governed by the Adamantine Law that "whatever can be misunderstood will be", and particularly in a contractual context, governed by the Attorney's Full Employment Codicil that "whatever can be litigated will be", this is pretty poor writing.

Comment: @StoneyB: IANAL, obviously. But if I were personally involved in some dispute where the other party was claiming the "capricious" interpretation (to my detriment in some way), I'd happily mortgage my house to defend my interpretation as being *what any reasonable person would understand the **intended** meaning to be*. We probably all tend to underestimate the extent to which that principle underpins legal judgements, simply because it's the *exceptions* that get all the media attention (they being the ones that need "fixing").

Comment: No-one wants to be taken to court, even if they're sure they'll win.

Comment: Probably no-one wants ***to be taken*** to court, since that choice of phrasing implies *the other party instigated the action, in the expectation that they'll win*. But an awful lot of people have relished the opportunity to taken *someone else* (or an organisation) to court if they think they've been wronged. And many of the more righteous-thinking among those litigants are doubtless highly gratified that they stood up for their rights, and successfully obtained legal judgement against whoever was "oppressing" them.

Comment: Which is exactly the point - no-one wants to be taken to court, but there are lots who want to be plaintiff, so you need to write your documents in such a way as to deny them the opportunity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You might take a look at the (to my mind very reasonable) doctrine of [*contra proferentem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra_proferentem).

Comment: @StoneyB: Ooh, good point. I was aware of, and agree with, that doctrine - but didn't recall it right now to apply to this situation.

Comment: @StoneyB: Which as the link points out, *is often applied to situations involving standardized contracts or where the parties are of **unequal bargaining power***. Which I take to mean if you're just the little man arguing against harsh treatment by a big outfit with big lawyers, justice will tend to side with you, not them. Even putting aside considerations of "natural justice", that would obviously be no more than we'd expect, since the big company doubtless had their contracts drafted up by expensive lawyers in the first place. (Even *more* expensive ones make sure the wording's right! :)

Comment: It can be applied in situations of equal power as well, as the very next clause indicates. The idea being that a drafter shouldn't be sneaky, so if there's any ambiguity it will be to their detriment - thus encouraging them to avoid ambiguity.